# How to add nodes into TreeView via Threads c#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, treeview

I want fill my treeview with >30000 nodes in multi level.

I use this code for fill it, but treeview get over 30 seconds time for fill it.

How can I use multi thread for increase speed to fill it ?

//in my windows form :

```
private void ThesaurusFrm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TreadPopulateTree();
        }

private void TreadPopulateTree()
        {
            System.Threading.Thread TrPopulateTree = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(PopulateTree));
            TrPopulateTree.Start();
        }

        private void PopulateTree()
        {
            FillTree.TvTrees = TvThesaurusNodes;
            FillTree Ft = new FillTree();
            var TreeItems = Db.LoadThesaurusTrees();

            if (TvThesaurusNodes.InvokeRequired)
                TvThesaurusNodes.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                {
                    Ft.LoadTrees(TreeItems);
                }));
        }
```

//in my FillTree class

```
public static TreeView TvTrees;

List<TreesFieldSet> TreeItems = new List<TreesFieldSet>();
public void LoadTrees(List<TreesFieldSet> TreeItems)
{
    this.TreeItems = TreeItems;

    TvTrees.Nodes.Clear();
    TvTrees.ShowPlusMinus = true;
    TvTrees.FullRowSelect = true;

    TvTrees.Nodes.Clear();
    TvTrees.BeginUpdate();
    LoadBaseNodes();
    TvTrees.EndUpdate();
    TvTrees.Refresh();
}

private void LoadBaseNodes()
{
    if (TreeItems != null)
    {
        int BaseParent = 0;
        TreeNode Node;
        foreach (TreesFieldSet Tfs in TreeItems)
        {
            if (Tfs.ParentId < BaseParent)
                BaseParent = Tfs.ParentId;
        }
        foreach (TreesFieldSet Tfs in TreeItems)
        {
            if (Tfs.ParentId == BaseParent)
            {
                Node = TvTrees.Nodes.Add(Tfs.Title);
                Node.Tag = Tfs.TreeId;
                GetChildren(Node);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void GetChildren(TreeNode Node)
{
    TreeNode ChNode = null;
    Int32 nodeCat = (Int32)Node.Tag;
    foreach (TreesFieldSet Tfs in TreeItems)
    {
        if (Tfs.ParentId == nodeCat)
        {
            ChNode = Node.Nodes.Add(Tfs.Title);
            ChNode.Tag = Tfs.TreeId;
            GetChildren(ChNode);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No never do multi-threading with UI, Reading is not a problem in some case but writing is always a problem.

You can defer the loading, i.e Load only what user can see, then load the children only when user clicks the node. I've answered a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19061220/2530848) see if that helps.

Typically you load only a "Node" and its "Immediate children" no more no less.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I agree. Don't preload 30k nodes. The users won't look at all those entries.. Keep loading when the user expands a node. Then you should load the subitems of all subitems of that node, i.e. you should always load one level more than is visible. In that way you get all the subnode-crosses to show correctly. If you need a search function it can use the data structure you keep in memory..

Comment: He may have wanted an even clearer advice against using multiple threads to access a UI element. He may have a bad day. Or mind your incorrect plural. Or simply love to downvote. Basic SO advice: Never mind a downvote or two!

Comment: @TaW All is well, I didn't get what you meant by *Or mind your incorrect plural*. Can you clarify?

Comment: One child, two children.